# GitHub Action Scheduling Fails on Issue Comment

Tags: github, github-actions

I was testing a GitHub Action to automatically put a “sensitive word” label when the listed below sensitive words are mentioned in the issue comments. I tried to schedule it for once a day (at the end of a day to be precise) but it's still triggered wherever an issue comment is added (not in accordance with the scheduled time). How can I fix that so that it runs once a day only? Also the question is if it's going to check the whole thing or just comments that were added throughout a day?

If I get rid of the `issue_comment:` line it gives me an error saying that this action can be applied on issue comments only.

```
name: 'Sensetive Words Detection'
on:
  schedule:
      - cron: '0 0 * * *'
  issue_comment:
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: Amwam/issue-comment-action@v1.3.1
        with:
          keywords: '["Google", "Netflix"]'
          labels: '["sensitive-word"]'
          assignees: '["author"]'
          github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

Any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: If it's running once a day, how's it supposed to know which comments to process? Why _not_ run it `on: issue_comment`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried but it didn't work

Comment: Use the GitHub API to get the comments since the last run and process them: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#comments